# What is best way to draw 250k points?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawing

I need to draw ~250'000 points with different colors from two-dimension array. I am trying to do it using SurfaceView. It works well but drawing takes 2-3 seconds (I am looking time between "Start draw"/"Draw done" log records). Possibly I am choose wrong way or doing something wrong. What is the most perfomance way to draw 250k points in Android?

Here is my code:

```
class MyDrawThread(private val surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) : Thread() {

    var isRunning = false
    var points: List<List<Int>>? = null

    override fun run() {
        var canvas: Canvas?
        while (isRunning) {
            points?.let { points ->
                canvas = null
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Start draw")
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null)
                    synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                        canvas!!.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
                        for ((x, list) in points.withIndex()) {
                            val paint = Paint()
                            for ((y, colorId) in list.withIndex()) {
                                paint.color = getColor(colorId) // Get color from hardcoded array by index
                                canvas!!.drawPoint(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), paint)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Draw done")
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(10000L)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  It seems like you're doing something wrong to get here.  If you were to try, the answer is OpenGL.  But don't expect that to work well either, how often do you see video games with 250K sprites?

Comment: @GabeSechan This is just a requirements specification. This is not a game or video, this is just a motionless points.